# How to avoiding starting with “it is”?

Tags: sentence, sentence-starts, dummy-it

I have a sentence fragment I must make into a sentence:

> Late August at the Los Angeles Zoo.

I use this sentence to begin a story. I really do not want to use “it is” though, because “it is” does not add new meaning. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have to make it into a sentence? Depending on what follows it, I don't see why you can't begin a story like that.

Comment: This is a question of style better suited for writers.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your fragment as the subject of an active sentence that adds action or flavor to your scene, for example:

"Late August at the Los Angeles Zoo stank of dead fish and tourist sweat."

(Note correction of the spelling of Los Angeles.)

Comment: @tchrist: Speaking of a period of time as having a smell strains your readerly sensibilities?